# How can I pass Entity To MediatR(I had a problem when I try)

Tags: c#, .net-core, containers, handler, mediatr

I have made the below class but I had an error
What I am trying to do is make a generic class for all queries throws MediatR

this is my class

```
public class GetAllBaseQuery<T> : IRequest<IResponseDTO>
    where T :class
{

    public class GetAllBaseQueryHandler<T> : IRequestHandler<GetAllBaseQuery<T>, IResponseDTO>
        where T : class
    {
        private readonly IBaseResponse _Repo;
        public GetAllBaseQueryHandler(IBaseResponse Repo)
        {
            _Repo = Repo;
        }
        public async Task<IResponseDTO> Handle(GetAllBaseQuery<T> query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var _rec= await _Repo.GetS<T>();
            if (_rec== null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return _rec;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the error message

```
Register your handlers with the container. See the samples in GitHub for examples
```

Comment: Post where/how you are registering mediatr with your container. Post how are you are using `GetAllBaseQueryHandler<T>`.

Comment: This the registration Code
services.AddMediatR(typeof(GetAllBaseQuery<>).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);